# UFW Firewall development mode

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, firewall, ufw

I would like to know how to enable Development/Testing mode on UFW firewall.

I'd like to automatically disable rules after few minutes to avoid the server locking out.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. How to execute a command after a few minutes?

You can use the `at` command.

The following command will execute a shell-script in 5 minutes from now

```
at -f path_to_shell_script now + 5 min
```

2. How to disable `UFW` rules?

The following command will turn off UFW completely and delete all the rules:

```
ufw reset
```

You can create a script called `ufw-reset.sh` which will include `ufw reset` as its content and to execute it using `at` to be executed in 5 minutes from now:

```
at -f ufw-reset.sh now + 5 min
```

- [Info about ufw](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-on-ubuntu-15-04/)
- [Info about at command](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/at-atq-atrm-batch-command-examples/)